# Query Wikidata for entity type(s)

Tags: java, freebase, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to get the types according to Freebase of a Wikipedia page. For example, for `Jeb Bush` I should get,

```
Politician, Organization leader, Organization founder, 
Person, Family member, Film actor, Political Appointer
```

I know how to do this in Freebase MQL, but now that Wikidata is going to replace Freebase, I wanted to update my APIs to be able to make the same query via Wikidata api. Can someone explain how?

Comment: On https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q221997 you can see what statements are available on Jeb Bush. Can you elaborate a bit on what it is you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's currently a good way to do this for Wikidata.  The closest analog to Freebase type is [P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) `instanceOf`, but all that'll give you for Jeb Bush is "Human".  Knowing that he's a person, you could also query [P106](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P106) `occupation` to discover that he's a banker and politician, but, as far as I know, there's no simple single query that will work across all entity types.

Perhaps at some point in the future P31 will be populated with additional information, but that'll probably depend on how the Wikidata community decides to use `instanceOf`.